# Regex Replace with Capture not ending with String

Tags: javascript, regex

I need some help

My pattern looks like

```
/°>(http|\/)([^|<]+?)(?!\.gif|\.jpg|\.mp|\.png|\.jpeg)<°/gi
```

I have 4 examples for what I try to achieve:

```
°>/w NICK<°
```

$1 -> /
$2 -> w NICK

```
°>http://google.de<°
```

$1 http
$2 ://google.de

```
°>/w NICK|/w NICK<°
```

no matches because of the |

```
°>http://google.de/img.png<°
```

no matches because of ending with .png

Now im totally clueless.... iI got the regex for the first 3 examples working, but can't get the lookahead for ending with a img extension
in c# i got it working but not for javascript

Comment: I'm confused. Which one is working and which isn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
°>(http|\/)(?![^|<]*\.(?:gif|jpe?g|mp|png)<)([^|<]+)<°
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j8JICb/1/)

**Details**:

- `°>` - a literal substring
- `(http|\/)` - Group 1: `http` or `/`
- `(?![^|<]*\.(?:gif|jpe?g|mp|png)<)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately after `http` or `/`, there are 0+ chars other than `|` and `<` followed with some extensions specified in the non-capturing group that are followed with `<`
- `([^|<]+)` - Group 2 matching 1 or more chars other than `|` and `<`
- `<°` - a literal substring.

Comment: thx - working flawless and of course the explaination helps me alot